# How do I download Windows 10 from my USB to my Ubuntu 16.4 PC?

Tags: windows

I have tried to download windows 10 onto my new PC that has come with ubuntu 16.4 software on it. However it is not working. Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly is failing and how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible because that software which is using to download is the .exe file for windows. You could download iso though VMbox with Windows or on Ubuntu with Wine. 
An alternative way is to download from somewhere else.